# What does "application/json'" really mean

Tags: javascript, http, web

I don't know application's mean in "application/json", and can I replace it with "text/json". so application = text ?

Comment: " and can I replace it with "text/json". so application = text ?" sure you can, but it might not be recognized anymore as json by applications reading your request

Comment: OMG I just want know what is application stand for

Comment: I will pay attention to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are meaning content type

`Application : Represents any kind of binary data.`

`Text : Represents any document that contains text and is theoretically human readable`

For more info visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want to express.Maybe I don't express my means